# How to mock extension methods created for Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.IDynamoDBContext

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit

When I try mocking extension method in c#, I get the error below:

```
System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: a => a.DeleteItemAsync<DynamoDbServiceTests.DummyObject>(It.IsAny<DynamoDbServiceTests.DummyObject>())
    Extension methods (here: Extensions.DeleteItemAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
```

So currently, since moq and Rihno cannot mock extension methods, I did a research and found out that a walk around would be to create a wrapper class and moq it instead. so I have worked on a wrapper class with the following structure:

Below is my extension method that is based on Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel.IDynamoDBContext:

```
namespace foo.DynamoDbExtensions
{
    public static class Extensions{
        public static async Task<ServiceResponse<T>> DeleteItemAsync<T>(this IDynamoDBContext context, T entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new FooDynamoDbExtensionsException("Item is not provided.");
            }

            await context.DeleteAsync(entity);
            ServiceResponse<T> remainingItems = context.GetItemsAsync(entity).Result;
            remainingItems.Message = "Resource Deleted";
            remainingItems.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            return remainingItems;
        }
        public static async Task<ServiceResponse<T>> GetItemsAsync<T>(this IDynamoDBContext context, T entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new FooDynamoDbExtensionsException("Item type (generic class) is not provided.");
            }

            List<T> data = await context.ScanAsync<T>(null).GetRemainingAsync();
            if (data?.Any() ?? false)
            {
                return new ServiceResponse<T>(isValid: true, "Resources Found", data, HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }

            return new ServiceResponse<T>(isValid: false, "Resources Not Found", data, HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

    }

}
```

Below is the service calling the the extension methods:

```
public class DynamoDbService : IDynamoDbService
{
    #region Properties

    private readonly IDynamoDBContext _context;

    #endregion 

    #region Constructors

    public DynamoDbService(IDynamoDBContext context, AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDbClient, IOptions<ExaiConfiguration> config)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods
    public async Task<ServiceResponse<T>> DeleteItem<T>(T request)
    {
        var result = await _context.DeleteItemAsync(request);

        return new ServiceResponse<T>(result.IsValid, result.Message, result.Data, result.StatusCode);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Below is what my wrapper class look like:

```
public interface IDynamoDBExtensionConfig: IDynamoDBContext
    {
        Task<ServiceResponse<T>> DeleteItemAsync<T>(IDynamoDBContext context, T entity);
        Task<ServiceResponse<T>> GetItemsAsync<T>(IDynamoDBContext context, T entity);
    }
    public  class DynamoDBExtensionConfig : IDynamoDBExtensionConfig
    { 
    
        public  async Task<ServiceResponse<T>> DeleteItemAsync<T>(IDynamoDBContext context, T entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new FooDynamoDbExtensionsException("Item is not provided.");
            }

            await context.DeleteAsync(entity);
            ServiceResponse<T> remainingItems = context.GetItemsAsync(entity).Result;
            remainingItems.Message = "Resource Deleted";
            remainingItems.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            return remainingItems;
        }
        public  async Task<ServiceResponse<T>> GetItemsAsync<T>(IDynamoDBContext context, T entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new FooDynamoDbExtensionsException("Item type (generic class) is not provided.");
            }

            List<T> data = await context.ScanAsync<T>(null).GetRemainingAsync();
            if (data?.Any() ?? false)
            {
                return new ServiceResponse<T>(isValid: true, "Resources Found", data, HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }

            return new ServiceResponse<T>(isValid: false, "Resources Not Found", data, HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
}
```

Below is how I am unit testing it:

```
[Fact]
        public async Task Handle_Delete_Pass()
        {
            // Arrange
            var resp = new AutoFaker<DynamoDbExtensions.Models.ServiceResponse<DummyObject>>().Generate();
            DummyObject entityParam = new AutoFaker<DummyObject>().Generate();

            Mock<IDynamoDBExtensionConfig> contextMockTemp = new Mock<IDynamoDBExtensionConfig>();
            contextMockTemp.Setup(a => a.DeleteItemAsync<DummyObject>(contextMockTemp.Object,It.IsAny<DummyObject>())).ReturnsAsync(resp);

            // Act
            var result =  new DynamoDbService(contextMockTemp.Object).DeleteItem(entityParam);

            // Assert
            Assert.NotNull(result);
            Assert.IsType<ServiceResponse<DummyObject>>(result);
        }
```

After I implemented the wrapper class, I am getting the error below

```
 Message: 
    System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)
    ---- System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

  Stack Trace: 
    Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
    Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
    Task`1.get_Result()
    Extensions.DeleteItemAsync[T](IDynamoDBContext context, T entity)
    DynamoDbService.DeleteItem[T](T request)
    DynamoDbServiceTests.Handle_Delete_Pass()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
    ----- Inner Stack Trace -----
    Extensions.GetItemsAsync[T](IDynamoDBContext context, T entity)
```

I am apparently getting a null pointer exception apparently. Any push in the right direction would be much appreciated